# WebViewでfavicon.icoロード時に404エラーが発生したらロードを無効にしたい

Tags: android, android-webview

Android StudioでWebViewを使用してurlをLoadするとfavicon.icoロード時に404エラーが発生しurlロードが完了しません。どうにかしてfavicon.icoのロードを無効にしたのですがご教授願います。

Comment: 近代的ブラウザ (Chrome/Edge 等等) は勝手に `favicon.ico` をロードする仕様ですし簡単に無効化できないし、無効化できちゃうと他の一般のサイトを見に行った際に挙動が変わるしでいいことないです。ロードされる前提であれこれ仕様考えたほうが絶対に楽できます。

Comment: https://qiita.com/fkonuma1208/questions/7d24fce8f6ee730d133d

Answer (score 0):

質問するときは必ず開発環境や実行環境に関する情報（IDEやターゲットOSのバージョンなど）を提示するようにしてください。それによって回答が変わる場合もあります。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

「404エラーが発生した場合はファビコンをロードしない」ということがAndroidのWebViewで実現できるかどうかは分かりませんが、[`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))メソッドをオーバーライドすることで、特定のファイルのダウンロード処理に割り込み、ダミーのファイルに差し替える、といったことはできます。

- [java - How to disable WebView load favicon.ico (i.e. specific URL)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473760)